# Location of Models in a Package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I wish to use models in my package. I've looked on laravel forums/blogs but can't find a definitive answer to this question.

**Where should my models be placed and how should they be namespaced?**

I know how to autoload my models etc but should the models go in:

```
panthro/package/src/models
```

and be namespaced:

```
panthro/package
```

OR be located at:

```
panthro/package/src/panthro/package/models
```

and be namespaced:

```
panthro/package/models
```

What is correct or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models can reside anywhere, as long as they can be found. However to keep things more consistent, I would advise you to put them in `panthro/package/src/` (or whatever the name of your package is), since `src` folder is almost the equivalent to `app` folder in your Laravel main project.

As for namespacing, I think it's fine just keep your namespacing as consistent as possible throughout your package, which usually starts with `Author\PackageName` for example:

```
namespace Panthro\Package;
```

Though I'd be much more specific than naming the package name as `Package`.

If you take a look at laravel's plugin libraries, you can learn how they do their namespacing and folder structure too.

Example:

[APIRouter](https://github.com/sjdaws/apirouter) - Very simple library

[Intervention (Laravel)](https://github.com/Intervention/image) - More comprehensive and bigger codebase but still easy to follow (structural-wise)

Depending on your package, if you have many types of models, it'll be wise to add another level of namespace for your models, otherwise you don't really have to.

Comment: Thanks, would I also need \models in the namespace? Could you direct me to the laravel examples you mentioned, I would like to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for adding examples but the APIRouter seems to go against what you suggest, the code is under sjdaws/src/Sjdaws/ApiRouter. As does Intervention - images/src/Intervention/Image. Also do you know of something that has uses models I can look at?

Comment: @panthro the locations depend on if you're using PSR-0 autoloading or PSR-4 autoloading. Using PSR-0 in the `src/` directory, a class at namespace `\Panthro\Package\Models\User` will be in `{vendor/}panthro/package/src/Panthro/Package/Models/User.php`, whereas using PSR-4 autoloading in the `src/` directory it'll be at `{vendor/}panthro/package/src/Models/User.php`. So if I were you I'd *just* think about namespaces, as the autoloading will define exactly where to put the actual files.

Comment: Thanks @alexrussell so if I went PSR-0, the namespace would be panthro/package/models? Also how does one decide between PSR-0 or PSR-4?

Comment: In general, PSR-0 is the 'current' way of doing it, and PSR-4 is the 'new' way. As you can see from my examples above, PSR-4 allows you to drop two unnecessary levels of directory structure, and that's really the only difference. I'd say for a Laravel package to stick with PSR-0 as it gives clear separation between your classes and the ancillary PHP files like config/lang/migrations, whereas using PSR-4 will put your 'top-level' classes directly in your `src/` directory. Also I think Laravel relies on PSR-0 for calculating where your views, config and lang files are relative to your main SP.

Comment: As for the NS, as @JofryHS has said it's really up to you. If you have a mix of controllers, models and other 'types' of class in your package you should probably do them like we've suggested: `\Panthro\Package\Models\User` for a model and `\Panthro\Package\Controller\UserController` for a controller, for example. But if your package only contains a model (or some models), then you may find that just putting the model in the root of your package's namespace (i.e. `\Panthro\Package\User`) is more sensible. Basically, think about how you would want to separate your classes and use NSes for that.